# 32 bit CRC with some inputs set to zero. Is this less accurate than dummy data?

Tags: crc, crc32, crc16

Sorry if I should be able to answer this simple question myself!

I am working on an embedded system with a 32bit CRC done in hardware for speed. A utility exists that I cannot modify that initially takes 3 inputs (words) and returns a CRC.

If a standard 32 bit was implemented, would generating a CRC from a 32 bit word of actual data and 2 32 bit words comprising only of zeros produce a less reliable CRC than if I just made up/set some random values for the last 2 32?

Depending on the CRC/polynomial, my limited understanding of CRC would say the more data you put in the less accurate it is. But don't zero'd data reduce accuracy when performing the shifts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zeros will be no different than some other value you might pick.  The input word will be just as well spread among the CRC bits either way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark Adler that zeros are mathematically no worse than other numbers.  However, if the utility you can't change does something bad like set the initial CRC to zero, then choose non-zero pad words.  An initial CRC=0 + Data=0 + Pads=0 produces a final CRC=0.  This is technically valid, but routinely getting CRC=0 is undesirable for data integrity checking.  You could compensate for a problem like this with non-zero pad characters, e.g. pad = -1.

Comment: That's only true if you put the data word in the _third_ of the three input words.  If you put the data word in the first word, and the two zero words in the second and third word, then this won't happen.

Comment: @Mark - What "this won't happen" do you mean?  With an initial hash of zero, then CRC(0,0,0) = 0.  CRC(0,-1,-1) and CRC(-1,-1,0) both result in non-zero CRCs. How does order matter?

Comment: CRC(_data_,0,0) results in the two zero words continuing to scramble the bits. CRC(0,0,_data_) could (if the CRC has no preconditioning) result in the CRC register remaining all zeros up to the point that _data_ is fed in.

Comment: @Mark, CRC(data,0,0) != 0 requires data != 0.  OP gave no guarantee in this regard.  Non-zero pad bytes covers this corner case for free.

Comment: True, but there will always exist a 32-bit word that gives an all zeros 32-bit CRC.  So that is unavoidable.